# How to group rows in sap.ui.table.TreeTable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, grouping, sapui5, treetable

I am using **sap.ui.table.TreeTable** to display the data but i want to group the existing table based on some common property in model just like grouping in list.
Currently i am using **sap.ui.table.TreeTable** like this

```
<mvc:View
        controllerName="sap.ui.table.sample.TreeTable.JSONTreeBinding.Controller"
        xmlns="sap.ui.table"
        xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
        xmlns:m="sap.m"
        xmlns:u="sap.ui.unified"
        xmlns:core="sap.ui.core">
    <m:Page
            showHeader="false"
            enableScrolling="false">
        <m:content>
            <TreeTable
                    id="TreeTableBasic"
                    rows="{path:'/rows', parameters: {arrayNames:['childrens']}}"
                    selectionMode="MultiToggle"
                    enableSelectAll="false"
                    ariaLabelledBy="title">

                <columns>
                    <Column width="13rem">
                        <m:Label text="Categories"/>
                        <template>
                            <m:Text text="{name}"/>
                        </template>
                    </Column>
            </TreeTable>
        </m:content>
    </m:Page>
</mvc:View>
```

In each ***child*** model data there is a property called **age**. So i want to group the rows based on age. Is there any way to group in **sap.ui.table.TreeTable** based on property in model just like in sap.m.List?